# reading data-frame with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to read some df with few columns and few rows where in some rows data are missing.
For example df looks like this, also elements of the df are separated sometimes with uneven number of spaces:

```
0.5 0.03   
0.1  0.2  0.3  2 
0.2  0.1   0.1  0.3
0.5 0.03  
0.1  0.2   0.3  2
```

Is there any way to extract this:

```
0.1  0.2  0.3  2 
0.2  0.1   0.1  0.3
0.1  0.2   0.3  2
```

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a text file or an existing dataframe?

Comment: provide minimal reproducible code/data

Comment: it is txt file ... sorry I forgot to mention this

Comment: Try   df['name columns'].str.strip()

Comment: When I try to load df I am getting an error >ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 5

Answer (score 1):

You can parse manually your file:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    df = pd.DataFrame([re.split(r'\s+', l.strip()) for l in fp]).dropna(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     0    1    2    3
1  0.1  0.2  0.3    2
2  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.3
4  0.1  0.2  0.3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {
    'col1': [0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1],
    'col2': [0.03, 0.2, 0.1, 0.03, 0.2],
    'col3': [np.nan, 0.3, 0.1, np.nan, 0.3],
    'col4': [np.nan, 2, 0.3, np.nan, 2]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(data.dropna(axis=0))
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.0
   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.3
   0.1   0.2   0.3   2.0
```